# Proving this function is increasing

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $\Omega$ is a connected open set in $\mathbb{C}$ that is symmetric in the real axis. With obvious notations, we write $\Omega = I \cup \Omega^+ \cup \Omega^-$.

Now suppose $f: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic with $f(\Omega^+) \subset \mathbb{C}^+$ and $f(I) \subset \mathbb{R}$. Also suppose that $(a,b)$ is an open interval contained in $I$.

Prove that the restriction of $f$ to $(a,b)$ is increasing.

This exercise was part of my study on Schwarz reflection principle. I think I have to prove that the (real) derivative of $f$ is larger than $0$ (rather than proving by the definition of increasing functions).

Any tips are welcome!

Comment: Let $ \Omega = \mathbb C$, $f(z)=\sin z$ and $(a,b)= (0, 2 \pi).$ The restriction of $f$ to $(a,b)$ is not increasing.

Comment: @Fred My bad it needed to say $f(\Omega^+) \subset \mathbb{C}^+$. I have edited the post

Answer (score 1):

According to [Cauchy–Riemann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations) and with usual notations we have for all $(x,y) \in \Omega$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} (x,y) = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} (x,y).$$

By hypothesis, for $x \in (a,b)$

$$\frac{d \overline{f}}{dx} (x)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} (x,0) = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} (x,0)$$ where $\overline f$ stands for the restriction of $f$ to $I$.

We have $\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} (x,0) \ge 0$. Otherwise the map $y \mapsto \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} (x,y)$ is less than $ c \lt 0$ in a neigborhood of $(x,0)$ and therefore $v(x, -c/2) \lt 0$ (according to Mean Value Theorem) in contradiction with the hypothesis $f(\Omega^+) \subset \mathbb{C}^+$.

We have proven that $\overline{f}^\prime(x) \ge 0$ and the desired result.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas! However this answer is incorrect, as you've chosen $c$ to be negative and thus there is no apparent contradiction here...

Comment: I did a proof by contradiction…

Comment: How so? As $c < 0$ it holds that $x + i \frac{c}{2} \in \Omega^-$. Because $v(x,c/2) < 0$ This gives $f(x + i \frac{c}{2}) = u(x,c/2) + iv(x,c/2) \in \mathbb{C}^-$. And $f(\Omega^-) \subset \mathbb{C}^-$ which is easy to prove from the assumptions

Comment: There was a typo in my answer that I edited.